# Stable life on Mercury

Tags: flora

Are plants able to live of Mercury? Are they able to grow in the ground and be edible by humans? 
I feel kinda silly asking this but I have to find out for a school project.

Comment: Your teacher isn't really asking you if life could exist on mercury. They are asking you to list out the conditions that plants need to live: liquid water, C02 and sunlight. For extra credit, mention the nitrogen cycle, the ammonia cycle and earth's magnetosphere.

Answer (score 5):

Plants need nutrients in the soil. Mercury, as far as I know, doesn't have those nutrients. Just lifeless rock.

Plants need CO2 from the atmosphere. Mercury doesn't have an atmosphere.

Plants need stable temperatures. The temperatures on Mercury vary from 400 degrees Celsius during the day, to -200 degrees Celsius at night. Any plants on its surface, living or dead, would either freeze or catch fire.

That's a big fat no.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know for a school project, you're not really in the right place.

Are earth's plants able to grow on Mercury? f*ck no!

using this information: https://www.space.com/18645-mercury-temperature.html

Mercury can get as hot as 427F, almost hot enough for paper (and plants) to spontaneously combust. Except there's no Oxygen, so you couldn't have a flame.

https://www.space.com/18644-mercury-atmosphere.html

The atmosphere is pretty darned toxic (to terrestrial life).

Could life maybe find a way? Sure, why not? But we haven't found any so far.